# Control Layer for Barchart in Leaflet JS

Tags: javascript, leaflet

this is my very first webmap. To visualize one of my data i am using leaflet minichart. And i successed to show the barchart. And now i tried to make a control layer for my barchart. but it says Uncaught ReferenceError: barChartMarker is not defined. how to solve this? and this is my code :

```
forEach(bar => {
            var options = {
                data: [
                    bar.ASKES / 3,
                    bar.BPJS / 3,
                    bar.KIS / 3
                ],
                chartOptions: {
                    'dataPoint1': {
                        fillColor: '#FEE5D9',
                        minValue: 0,
                        maxValue: 30,
                        maxHeight: 30,
                        displayText: function (value) {
                            return value.toFixed(2);
                        }
                    },
                    'dataPoint2': {
                        fillColor: '#FCAE91',
                        minValue: 0,
                        maxValue: 30,
                        maxHeight: 30,
                        displayText: function (value) {
                            return value.toFixed(2);
                        }
                    },
                    'dataPoint3': {
                        fillColor: '#FB6A4A',
                        minValue: 0,
                        maxValue: 30,
                        maxHeight: 30,
                        displayText: function (value) {
                            return value.toFixed(2);
                        }
                    }
                    }
                },
             
              
                weight: 1,
                color: '#000000',
                }
                     
                var barChartMarker = L.minichart(bar.location, options);
                map.addLayer(barChartMarker);
            
                })

    var overlays = {
            "Barchart": barChartMarker
        };
    
        L.control.layers(overlays).addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't access a variable from outside which is defined inside a function.

Change to:

```
var barChartGroup = L.featureGroup().addTo(map);
var overlays = {
   "BarChart" : barChartGroup
};

forEach(bar => {
    var options = {
        data: [
            bar.ASKES / 3,
            bar.BPJS / 3,
            bar.KIS / 3
        ],
        chartOptions: {
            'dataPoint1': {
                fillColor: '#FEE5D9',
                minValue: 0,
                maxValue: 30,
                maxHeight: 30,
            }
        }
        .....
        weight: 1,
        color: '#000000',
    }

    var barChartMarker = L.minichart(bar.location, options);
    barChartGroup.addLayer(barChartMarker);
})

L.control.layers(overlays).addTo(map);
```

Comment: i dont want categorize my barchart by name, i just want one layer that can show all my barchat. how can i do that?

Comment: and if i edit bar.name as a string. it just work with one of my barchat, not all of them